Combining multiple functions into a single function of the same type in Rust
I am new to Rust, and I am wondering what is the best way to solve this basic example. I am combining two functions of type MathLogFn by returning a closure. As I understand, a closure is needed in order to have access to math_log_fns in the surrounding environment.
The below code compiles, however is there a way to refactor this so that the return type of combine_math_log_fns() is MathLogFn?
type MathLogFn = fn(u32, u32);

fn log_sum(n1: u32, n2: u32) {
    println!("{}", n1 + n2);
}

fn log_product(n1: u32, n2: u32) {
    println!("{}", n1 * n2);
}

fn combine_math_log_fns(math_log_fns: Vec<MathLogFn>) -> Box<dyn Fn(u32, u32)> {
    Box::new(move |n1: u32, n2: u32| {
        for mlf in &math_log_fns {
            mlf(n1, n2);
        }
    })
}

fn main() {
    let mlfs: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u32, u32)>> = vec![
        Box::new(log_sum),
        Box::new(log_product),
        combine_math_log_fns(vec![log_sum, log_product]),
    ];
}

What did you try and what were you expecting?
I tried refactoring, but the compiler gives errors that it does not have access to math_log_fns unless a closure is used:
fn combine_math_log_fns(math_log_fns: Vec<MathLogFn>) -> MathLogFn {
    fn combined(n1: u32, n2: u32) {
        for mlf in &math_log_fns {
            mlf(n1, n2);
        }
    }

    combined
}


Closures that capture data cannot be cast to function pointers. Boxing is necessary in this case.

The first step in one plausible solution to this issue is to redefine type MathLogFn = Box<dyn Fn(u32, u32)>;

Once type_alias_impl_trait is available in stable you'll be able to do type MathLogFn = impl Fn(u32, u32); and change the meta-function to return MathLogFn. This will eliminate the overhead of boxing for the returned closure. However, you'd have to change the generic type of the Vec argument to Box<dyn Fn(u32, u32)>, or keep it as fn(u32, u32) which will preclude the use of capturing closures as inputs.

If all functions are known at compile time and are simple fns, then this is possible with a bit of unsafe code. The question is, is it worth it?

This answer expands on a comment I wrote.
Easier option
In the line type MathLogFn = fn(u32, u32);, fn(u32, u32) is a function pointer type. These pointers can only point to code, not extra runtime data. A closure is different; it can capture extra runtime data, specifically variables from its environment.

fn log_sum captures no variables from its environment, so it can be used as a function pointer
fn log_product captures no variables from its environment, so it can be used as a function pointer
fn combined uses math_log_fns from its environment, so it must be converted to a closure

Not that we know that combine_math_log_fns should return a closure, you can choose between:

Box<dyn Fn(u32, u32)> which can't be cloned and, if a Clone bound was added, would be inefficient to clone
Rc<dyn Fn(u32, u32)>, which can be efficiently cloned
Arc<dyn Fn(u32, u32) + Send + Sync>, like Rc but usable in multi-threaded contexts

Then, you might as well redefine your type alias with your chosen type for maximum interoperability:
type MathLogFn = Box<dyn Fn(u32, u32)>;

The main downside is that Box<dyn Fn> (and Rc/Arc versions) add indirection in the form of allocation and dynamic dispatch.
Harder option with less indirection
If you want to avoid Box<dyn ...> but don't mind relaxing the calling syntax of a math log function, you could also switch to using an enum:
enum MathLogFn {
    Single(fn(u32, u32)),
    Sequential(Vec<MathLogFn>),
}

impl MathLogFn {
    pub fn call(&self, n1: u32, n2: u32) {
        match self {
            Self::Single(function) => function(n1, n2),
            Self::Sequential(functions) => {
                for function in functions {
                    function.call(n1, n2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

impl From<fn(u32, u32)> for MathLogFn {
    fn from(f: fn(u32, u32)) -> MathLogFn {
        Self::Single(f)
    }
}

fn log_sum(n1: u32, n2: u32) {
    println!("{}", n1 + n2);
}

fn log_product(n1: u32, n2: u32) {
    println!("{}", n1 * n2);
}

fn combine_math_log_fns(math_log_fns: Vec<MathLogFn>) -> MathLogFn {
    MathLogFn::Sequential(math_log_fns)
}

fn main() {
    let mlfs: Vec<MathLogFn> = vec![
        (log_sum as fn(u32, u32)).into(),
        (log_product as fn(u32, u32)).into(),
        combine_math_log_fns(vec![
            (log_sum as fn(u32, u32)).into(),
            (log_product as fn(u32, u32)).into()
        ]),
    ];

    for f in mlfs {
        f.call(1, 2);
    }
}

3rd party library option
Finally, if you use nightly Rust, you can try using ffd::Func to reduce indirection while keeping a standard calling syntax.

In Rust, function pointers (fn(u32, u32)) and closures (Fn, FnMut, FnOnce) serve different purposes. Function pointers are simple pointers to functions that do not capture any environment, whereas closures can capture variables from their surrounding scope. This fundamental difference impacts how you can structure and return functions in your code. What you can do, if you what to avoid the heap allocation, is to use references to closures.
type MathLogFn = fn(u32, u32);

fn log_sum(n1: u32, n2: u32) {
    println!("{}", n1 + n2);
}

fn log_product(n1: u32, n2: u32) {
    println!("{}", n1 * n2);
}

fn combine_math_log_fns(math_log_fns: Vec<MathLogFn>) -> Box<dyn Fn(u32, u32)> {
    Box::new(move |n1: u32, n2: u32| {
        for mlf in &math_log_fns {
            mlf(n1, n2);
        }
    })
}

fn main() {
    let tmp = combine_math_log_fns(vec![log_sum, log_product]);
    let mlfs: Vec<&dyn Fn(u32, u32)> = vec![
        &log_sum,
        &log_product,
        &tmp
    ];
    for mlf in mlfs {
        mlf(2, 3);
    }
}

in alternative, if you need "more" lifetime, but still want to optimize heap allocation, you can define an enum as it was already said, like this one:
type MathLogFn = fn(u32, u32);

enum FunOrClosure {
    FnClose(Box<dyn Fn(u32, u32)>),
    MathLogFn(MathLogFn),
}

impl FunOrClosure {
    fn call(&self, n1: u32, n2: u32) {
        match self {
            FunOrClosure::FnClose(f) => f(n1, n2),
            FunOrClosure::MathLogFn(f) => f(n1, n2),
        }
    }
}


fn log_sum(n1: u32, n2: u32) {
    println!("{}", n1 + n2);
}

fn log_product(n1: u32, n2: u32) {
    println!("{}", n1 * n2);
}

fn combine_math_log_fns(math_log_fns: Vec<MathLogFn>) -> Box<dyn Fn(u32, u32)> {
    Box::new(move |n1: u32, n2: u32| {
        for mlf in &math_log_fns {
            mlf(n1, n2);
        }
    })
}

fn main() {
    let mlfs: Vec<FunOrClosure> = vec![
        FunOrClosure::MathLogFn(log_sum),
        FunOrClosure::MathLogFn(log_product),
        FunOrClosure::FnClose(combine_math_log_fns(vec![log_sum, log_product])),
    ];
    for mlf in mlfs {
        mlf.call(2, 3);
    }
}

